# Is Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1 and Ubuntu 14.0.4.1 same thing?

Tags: gnome

please i know this is a silly question but i am new to Ubuntu and just wanted to know if Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.1 the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

These both only differ in term of desktop environment.

**[Ubuntu Gnome](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/)** (formerly Ubuntu GNOME Remix) is official flavor of Ubuntu, featuring the GNOME desktop environment.
It  is a mostly pure GNOME desktop experience built from the Ubuntu repositories.

But when we say **[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)**, it generally means Ubuntu with Unity desktop.

Comment: Ok, but in comparable terms of features in desktop environment, which between GNOME and Unity is best?

Comment: It is matter of personal choice. Additionally, You can install both desktop environment on your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same. GNOME is a [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), giving you a set of tools and a GUI. whereas Ubuntu is the *distribution*.

> A Linux distribution is most simply described as a particular assortment of application and utility software, packaged together with the Linux kernel in such a way that its "out-of-the-box" capabilities meet most of the needs of its particular end-user base.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was looking to install the the GNOME and i already have Ubuntu installed. Now i can go ahead. Thanks